# How can I get excel match one cell to another set of values and print the values of third to a fourth?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need some help with the following:

There is four columns one is first is imported the two others are standard info (list) and the fourth is what we need to export.

Can someone help me with this please???

I can't get excel to think something like:

Check if A4 matches any of C4 to C8.
If yes show the D cell next to the C cell in F4.

Sorry to be a pain, any help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Theo

Comment: Have you tried `dlookup`?

Comment: Please show your code.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a job for INDEX-MATCH. In F4:

```
=INDEX($D4:$D8, MATCH($A4, $C4:$C8, FALSE))
```

What this does:

1. Looks for an exact match (`FALSE`) of `$A4` within the range `$C4:$C8` and outputs the relative row index where it found the match.
2. Gets the value from the range `$D4:$D8`, in column 1 and the row it found in step 1.